# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, androidx

I know it could look like [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355/google-material-design-library-error-program-type-already-present-android-suppo) but I could not fix it with the solution proposed and I could not comment on it too.
The Error is :

```
Program type already present: 
android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy, sources=[Unknown 
source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I'm trying to create an app using firebase there's is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 27
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01'

// ML Kit dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:17.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I pass over every file to be sure the import was good, I Also add

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false
```

There's my Project Gradle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I use Android Studio 3.1.4

Comment: For now, I just stop using androidx and it's working as fine as possible, I still hope being able to find the problem and merging to androidx

Comment: I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560036/6570945). Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @AshuTyagi, I was able to migrate. 
I use your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560036/6570945) + the **Refractor > Migrate to AndroidX**.
After that, I review my import to migrate them manually to androidx (the Nullable for example).
It compiles and run but my apps can’t start on my device anymore, I’ll have to find out why but still closer to the solution than before.

Comment: libGDX project check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377080/5733853

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This happened to me when I tried to migrate to Android X.The reason behind is that not all libraries have been migrated to Android X.

- **You may manually remove dependencies.** : Try to see all dependencies and find out the conflicting one. You may use *Gradle View* plugin for Android Studio or use *class navigation* from menu. (In android Studio: **Navigation -> class**; Now a search box appears and tick 'include non project items'; paste the whole class name creating error and search now; Find out the class having this dependency and remove manually!).  **Please check if you have any import statements left in files which uses the non AndoirdX dependencies still. If yes, please remove them too.**

**or**

- In Android studio, **Refractor -> Migrate to AndroidX**.

**or alternatively(manual way)**

- add following to **gradle.properties** .

```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true
```

This makes Android Studio to migrate all dependencies. For more info please check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar problem. In my case, it was because I am using Glide library and androidx. This solution works for me:

1. Set enableJetifier value to `true`
2. Update Gradle build tool to 3.3.0-alpha08 with Gradle version 4.9

[source](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3185)

Answer (score 2):

in my case just change your firebase version from

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
> ```
>
> to
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

you can correct it by adding these to your gradle.properties

```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true
```

but in some cases it wont be correct like libGDX games to work correctly in libGDX games you should change these codes in build.gradle:

```
configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
configurations.getByName("natives").copy().files.each { jar ->
    def outputDir = null
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
    if (outputDir != null) {
        copy {
            from zipTree(jar)
            into outputDir
            include "*.so"
        }
    }
}
```

it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio menu Navigate --> Class --> All (check that "Include in all places" checkbox is on) type your Class (INotificationSideChannel) and you will see more than one package of dependencies - just remove one of it from your gradle.build!
It often problem when you use both android and androidx dependencies in one project.