# android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, support-v4

**com.hendraanggrian.appcompat:socialview:0.1** library work with androidx. when i add this library to my project I got support.v4 error :

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

for solving this issue I add below code to gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false
android.enableD8 = false
```

but not affect. another solution i tried below code

```
configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
//        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
//        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    }
```

that not affect.

also i tried to get dependencies tree to find duplicates with this command

```
./gradlew dependencies -q
```

but got error. another thing that may help is that i use kotlin in some cases in this project

the problem is that when i build project and test with adb project built successfully but when i try to build apk in android studio this error appeares

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918301/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannelst/54178126#54178126

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i migrate all project to androidx and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
After I changed the version of Android Gradle Plugin to 3.2.0-rc03.
(After you change, you should change to gradle version to 4.6)

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html
In this article, they said they rewrote bytecode and resources of JAR and AAR dependencies to reference the new androidx-package classes and artifacts at 3.2.0-alpha14. 
Prev version of Android Gradle Plugin might have android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy. 
So if we want to use androidx, we should change the version of Android Gradle Plugin after 3.2.0-alpha14.